# Python Tkinter custom msgbox fails during import

Tags: python, tkinter, import

I am trying to create a custom text entry box that has a text entry field in the center and can return the user's input. I'm specifically trying to make something that can be imported and re-used in other programs. My current iteration uses an "inputdialog" class that works fine for getting the input when it's in it's own .py file, but if I try to import the module into another script, the "ok" button seemingly does nothing, and the "x" button throws an "ImportError: cannot import name 'inputdialog'" error after closing the pop-up.

The following is my code which currently works if run as a standalone script:

```
from tkinter import *

class inputdialog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.withdraw()
        self.top = Toplevel(self.root)


        Label(self.top, text="Value").pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.top)
        self.e.pack(padx=5)

        b = Button(self.top, text="OK", command=self.ok)
        b.pack(pady=5, padx=5, side="right")
        self.root.mainloop()

    def ok(self):
        self.value = self.e.get()
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = inputdialog()
    print(test.value)
```

The following is how I've imported this module into another program, which does not currently work:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # These two lines below are needed to make sure that "askopenfilename"
    # doesn't show it's top level tkinter window
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    entdbemp = askopenfilename(title="Please select a file: ")

    # Here is my non-working module call
    master = inputdialog()
    print(master.value)
```

Why would my "OK" button cease to function when imported? Is there any way I can fix my code to allow it to be imported? Is there a better way of trying to make an importable text entry module using tkinter?

Comment: One problem is that you're creating two instances of `Tk`. Tkinter is designed to have exactly one instance of `Tk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with importing. The problem is that in your second example you call `Tk()` twice: once in each file. Also, when you call 'destroy' you are only removing the GUI from the screen, you are not exiting the mainloop.

To make this work, you need to remove the lines that create a root in the inputdialog class, move the `mainloop()` call to a point after starting the class, and then call the `quit` method for the toplevel window (not the root window):

```
from tkinter import *
class inputdialog:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.value = None
        self.top = Toplevel(master)

        Label(self.top, text="Value").pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.top)
        self.e.pack(padx=5)

        b = Button(self.top, text="OK", command=self.ok)
        b.pack(pady=5, padx=5, side="right")

    def ok(self):
        self.value = self.e.get()
        self.top.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    master = inputdialog(root)
    root.mainloop()
    print(master.value)
```

If you want to be neat and proper: rather than making a class that wraps around a different class, in OOP and GUIs we like to make a subclass:

```
import tkinter as tk

class inputdialog(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)

        self.value = None

        tk.Label(self, text="Value").pack()
        self.e = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e.pack(padx=5)

        b = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.ok)
        b.pack(pady=5, padx=5, side="right")

    def ok(self):
        self.value = self.e.get()
        self.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    master = inputdialog(root)
    root.mainloop()
    print(master.value)
```

Also, wildcard imports (`from module import *`) are ugly and against PEP8; don't use them.

BTW, the [`easygui`](http://pythonhosted.org/easygui/tutorial.html#enterbox) package has done all this already; you may just want to install and use that.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this when I get home. I don't do a ton of oop, will remember to make a subclass in the future. I thought the double Tk()s might be an issue but wasn't sure how to mitigate that. As for the wildcard import, i grabbed the base code from a hasty example and never fixed it ( sorry!)

Comment: Hey @Novel, I copied over your code above and the same issues still persists, but then I copied your code to another of my PCs and it worked fine. Very strange. I'm going to mark this as answered because it appears to work; I guess I just have something wrong with my environment.